# Dumping Cognito users to JSON using Ruby causes the results to be [FILTERED]

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-ruby

I'm trying to backup Cognito users using the AWS Ruby SDK.  Everything is going well except when I call to_json on any users attributes, it outputs every value as "[FILTERED]".  If I use to_yaml instead it seems to work fine.

Is there a reason that JSON output is filtered?  Is there an option or something to turn the filtering off?

Answer (score 1):

I observed the same problem when using Amazon Textract via the `aws-sdk-textract` gem. In my case the object returned was native to the client gem. Converting the object to a Hash before converting to JSON replaced the `[FILTERED]` values with the underlying data.

```
response.to_h.to_json
```